# Recovering absolute amount of change in rotation from incomplete quaternion data set

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, data-analysis, missing-data, quaternions

(even though this question is really about dimensionality/geometry of unit quaternions, I think it fits better here than on math.SE since it's very applied and about processing of a concrete data set)

Dear all,

I recorded human head rotation data in virtual reality using Unity and made a mistake:

While I thought I logged Euler `x y z` angles, what I actually logged were quaternion `x y z` values (giving me the angle of rotation), missing the `w` value (which would've given me the magnitude of rotation around the given axis).

This is what the stored data looks like (note the missing `quat_w` value):

```
index,quat_x,quat_y,quat_z
...
78,-0.6110323,0.03070354,0.0267202
79,-0.6051921,0.03211467,0.02481551
80,-0.5986348,0.03383164,0.02287504
81,-0.5914301,0.03582972,0.02073469
82,-0.5838193,0.03801479,0.01857705
83,-0.5749278,0.04081578,0.0161825
84,-0.5650933,0.04400427,0.01373928
85,-0.5529117,0.04804236,0.01112504
86,-0.5384405,0.05273005,0.008707636
...
```

(full snippet at https://pastebin.com/a17nfxm9)

**The information I would like to get out of my data is the absolute amount of rotation over a given set of subsequent rows** (samples were logged at 90Hz). So intuitively, if subjects rotated their head a lot, the output value should be higher than if they rotated it less.

Since Unity uses normalized quaternions, I am able to restore the fourth missing value `w` up to its sign (since `x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 = 1`). This however does not yield unique results when I stick with either all positive-signed or all negative-signed values for `w` and apply the formula for `\theta` (smallest angle of rotation to get from one quaternion to another) provided in [this response](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/90098/506822) and sum up the results for neighbouring rows.

Is there a way to get the wanted information from my incomplete data set, or should I give up the search?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Sorry for the data loss, and hopefully it wasn't weeks of recording (and perhaps even paying the testers). If there's huge incentive to try recover a bit of fuzzy data, one thing you could try is to Machine Learning train deduction of the w based on x y z by using a new recording of your own head recording as x y z input, providing proportional rewards to how close the machine guesses the w (which you now recorded). Once the machine is trained, it could be let loose on the incomplete data set. But, a major workaround, and hopefully someone can find a better solution!

Comment: For each row, you have 2 possible values for w, correct? I would try finding the sequence of W values which minimizes the amount of motion for the user's head overall. There are 2^90 possible combinations for each second but a greedy method might work. That is, where you start at the first entry with an arbitrary choice for W, then choose the W for the next entry which minimizes the theta between that entry and the previous one.

Comment: @Ruzihm the greedy strategy could actually work quite well, since I'm not interested in the actual values of W but just the sum of theta over all neighbouring rows. thank you, I'll give it a shot!

Comment: @mk04 Good luck! And if you find a solution that works, you are [most welcome](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to answer your own question below, to help future visitors who come with a similar problem.